# Add rich text editor in wp plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, tinymce, text-editor

I added a tinymce text editor into my wp plugin using these codes:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'editor_admin_init');
add_action('admin_head', 'editor_admin_head');

function editor_admin_init(){
wp_enqueue_script('post');
wp_enqueue_script('word-count');
wp_enqueue_script('editor');
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
}

function editor_admin_head(){
wp_tiny_mce();
}
```

And displaying it:

```
the_editor("", "content", "", false);
```

My question is, if i input some things into the editor. Where does it saves the data? On which table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you setup your plugin, this 'could be' saved as an option,

ie:

```
<?php

// Grab our options, IF your using Options
// if not you can create and use your own tables to store data
$options = get_option('your_plugin_options');

// using a hidden field on the form called action with a value of 'save'    
if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']=='save')){

   $options['main_content'] = trim($_POST['content']);

   $newOptions = array( 'main_content' => $options['main_content'] );

   update_option('your_plugin_options', $newOptions );   
}
?>
```

this will create an Option within the wordpress table wp_options

then, if you want to ref that option you simply give it a shout.

```
<?php
$options = get_option('your_plugin_options');
$new_content = $options['main_content'];

echo $options['main_content'];
//or
echo $new_content;
?>
```

hopefully this points you in the right direction.
have a read through:

// using the get option
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

// updating options
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option

// creating seperate tables in your plugin
http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Good luck 
Marty